# Webpack multiple entries output without "[name]" pattern

Tags: webpack, output, multiple-entries

I want to determine the file name output without the `[name]` string pattern. I have multiple entries and want to determine the file name by logic which uses the Entry. Something like this:

```
output: {
        path: getFilePath(),
        filename: getFileName(),
    },
```

The problem is the entry is not known when I run the webpack config.

Answer (score 0):

I checked in the [Webpack multiple entries docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/#multiple-entry-points) and didn't find any way to do it.

Then, I found when you give the `filename` a function, not running it like here:

```
output: {
        path: getFilePath(),
        filename: getFileName,
    },
```

The Webpack will call this function with an Entry argument and it will contain the entry it running now, for example:

```
    function getFileName(entry) {
    if (entry.chunk.name === "name1") {
        return "Test1";
    }
    return "Test2";
}
```